# Difference between "per day" and "the day"

Tags: grammar, difference

What is the difference between this "the day" and "per day" before?

> It happened per day before this(something).
>
> It happened the day before this(something).

Answer (score 2):

"Per" and "The" are very different words. As a result, your first example makes no sense at all, to the extent that I cannot offer an alternative!

Your second example is better; without knowing the full context, I would probably alter it to:
"(Something) happened the day before this."

Comment: How would you use "per"? any sentence

Comment: I am paid ten dollars per day

Comment: "My speed was ten miles per hour."

Comment: @Boyep The meaning of the first sentence is clear: *it happened **each / every** day before this.* What's left out is the number of times it happened. For instance,  *it happened **twice** per day before this* or *it happened **four times** per day before this.*